# Angular2 getting build error when using prod mode

Tags: angular

I have a project that builds and runs fine EXCEPT when built with --prod.  With the branch an update was made to app.module.ts to add a new class.  When compiling with --prod the error seems to suggest it is not seeing the update in app.module.ts to include the new class in the imports.

I have done some looking and while I see mentions to assertions being ignored when compiling in --prod I am not able to figure out why I get different compile results.

Suggestions where to look?  The error being received is shown below.  As noted - this error does NOT occur when not using the --prod switch.

```
efultz@efultz-VirtualBox:~/src/mazarbul$ ng build --prod
Hash: df9a28c95c9046c1a94c                                                              
Time: 22208ms
chunk    {0} main.fa72ef2ee5f706de666c.bundle.js (main) 1.46 kB {2} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} styles.c5b565451a586f1a4277.bundle.css (styles) 69 bytes {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} vendor.b736603c27f47849d40c.bundle.js (vendor) 1.08 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} inline.09dee9cfb318b8246b24.bundle.js (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in Cannot determine the module for class DialogComponent in /home/efultz/src/mazarbul/src/app/dialog/components/dialog.component.ts! Add DialogComponent to the NgModule to fix it.

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/home/efultz/src/mazarbul/src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 5:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

Comment: is DialogComponent included in a module? The error is related to that component

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was able to remove dialog.component.ts and the problem went away - and turned out that module must have been a residual from an earlier iteration.  Still don't understand why dev would work and prod would fail.